# AngularJS directive works, but not in test scenario

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

I have the following directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('epicuro.ui.authorization')
    .directive('ngIfRole', function(AuthorizationContext) {
        return {
            priority: 601,
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            compile: function($element, $attr) {
                if ($attr.ngIf) {
                    $attr.ngIf = '(' + $attr.ngIf + ') &&';
                } else {
                    $attr.ngIf = '';
                }

                $attr.ngIf += 'hasRole()';

                return function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
                    var value = $attr.ngIfRole;
                    var requiredRole = $scope.$eval(value);

                    $scope.hasRole = function () {
                        return AuthorizationContext.hasRole(requiredRole);
                    };
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

It works fine. The element with this attribute gets hidden when the user doesn't have the required role. But now I'm trying to create a test scenario around it, and I can't get it to work:

```
describe('The ngIfRole Directive', function () {
    'use strict';

    var $scope,
        $element,
        compileDirective,
        AuthorizationContext = { hasRole: jasmine.createSpy('hasRole') };

    beforeEach(module('epicuro.ui.authorization', function($provide) {
        $provide.value('AuthorizationContext', AuthorizationContext);
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        compileDirective = function(html){
            $element = angular.element(html);
            $compile($element)($scope);
            $scope.$apply();
        };
    }));

    it('Calls the AuthorizationContext to see if the element should be displayed', function() {
        AuthorizationContext.hasRole.and.returnValue(true);

        compileDirective('<div ng-if-role="\'role\'"></div>');

        expect(AuthorizationContext.hasRole).toHaveBeenCalledWith('role');
    });
});
```

The expectation fails saying the hasRole method is never called. If I replace the ng-if-role attribute by 'ng-if="hasRole()"', the test passes, so it looks like the whole compilation phase goes well.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Argh, sorry. Just figured out it doesn't work outside the test either anymore! Maybe since upgrade to angular 1.4? If only I had written this test earlier....